# How do I store login data when scraping a website using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website for data that is stored behind a link on a homepage to which I am redirected after logging in. I have set up my code to access the website to log in, but I cannot find a solid method of getting the code to store whatever cookie contains my login info and use it to navigate the site. If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

As an example of what it is I am trying to do: imagine that I am logging in to my Facebook account using Python, and I wish to scrape my own profile for my account information or settings - which obviously requires my login information to be retained after actually logging in - after navigating there from my dashboard or whatever the main page is called. I am searching for a way to apply this concept to websites in general.

I am using Python3 and the BeautifulSoup library, as well as the requests library.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `requests` session - this will hold the cookies for you. Read the documentation https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: You could also try Selenium - it holds state and such since it's basically just a browser